# Insert a lot of records into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list with a lot of (500+) codes and I want to insert it into database.

For example: User given codes to textarea and codes are seperated by new line (`\n`). In PHP it is `$_POST['codes']`. Of course I can just use `explode()` function and insert all codes in loop, but I'm thinking it's not a good idea with 500 repeatitions.

So, how can I do this the most optimal?

Comment: it's ok to explode the field

Comment: Have you tried it? 500 inserts is practically nothing.

Comment: 500-1000 repeats is nothing for both PHP and MySQL. So just explode and insert...

Comment: Probably best to use a prepared statement as well to speed it up that little bit.

Comment: Time isn't an issue and `$_POST['codes']` means: data is already in the memory anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the size of your data, you could make it all into a single query if you are worried about number of separate inserts:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable(`People`, `Places`, `Ideas`, `things`)
             VALUES ('40', '15', '0',  '0'),
             ('0',  '5',  '10', '0'),
             ('10', '0',  '11', '12')");
```

(example from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10286687/486780)

Comment: Don't recommend `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). It's advised to use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Comment: Of course, you are 100% right about prepared statements. But as a proof of concept, this would be one way of doing it.

Comment: It's crucial for this question: if you run prepared statements, the SQL interpreter has to interpret the query only once and you can run the same query over and over again at high speed. That's a totally different syntax from yours.

Comment: You are totally right. Missed the point of your initial comment a bit. All I can do is agree now.